# Print all paths in a tree (Not just root to nodes)

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

So how would you print all paths in a tree. Here the condition is that we don't only want paths starting from the root or paths in the sub-tree.

For example:

```
     2
    / \
   8   10
  /\   /
 5  6 11
```

So the program should return:

```
2-8
2-10
2-8-5
2-8-6
8-5
8-6
2-10-11
10-11
5-8-2-10-11
5-8-2-10
and so on...
```

One approach is to find the LCA between every distinct pair of nodes and then print the path from the LCA to both nodes (reverse in the left subtree and in order in the right subtree). But the complexity here would be O(n^3). Is there a more efficient solution ?

Comment: Assume it is a binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the result, not in the algoritm, create the nodes and relations in neo4j with

```
merge (n2:node{n:2})-[:down]->(n8:node{n:8})-[:down]->(:node{n:5})
merge (n2)-[:down]->(:node{n:10})-[:down]->(:node{n:11})
merge (n8)-[:down]->(:node{n:6})
```

then query

```
match p=(a)-[r:down *]-(b) return nodes(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you tree has distinct nodes, you can:

1. Create a map having key as int and value as vector. The key stands for each node you encounter and vector is for storing all the nodes that you will traverse under the node.
2. Pass this map by value to each node. You can have a function like:

   ```
   void printAllPaths(node *proot, map<int, vector<int> > m)
   ```
3. Whenever you encounter a new node n, do the following

   > a) For each k from set of keys
   >
   > b) Add n to the value vector of k.
   >
   > c) Print all keys followed by their value vectors.
   >
   > d) Also insert new key as n into the map with empty vector as value.

Note: If your tree has duplicate nodes you a multimap will help you keep track. c++ STL will serve you well in this case.

Comment: What kind of traversal would you suggest the above method would work ? Complexity ?

Comment: i think this will only give path from parent to siblings , but not from siblings to other siblings